# Custom loss function with Gradient Tape, TF2.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradienttape

I am trying to use a custom loss function in my `Keras` sequential model (TensorFlow 2.6.0). This custom loss (ideally) will calculate the data loss plus the residual of a physical equation (say, diffusion equation, Navier Stokes, etc.). This residual error is based on the model output derivative wrt its inputs and I want to use `GradientTape`.

In this MWE, I removed the data loss term and other equation losses, and just used the derivative of the output wrt its input. The dataset can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv).

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf #tf.__version__ = '2.6.0'
# load the dataset
dataset = loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8] #X.shape = (768, 8)
y = dataset[:,8]
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)

def customLoss(y_true,y_pred):
    x_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(model.input, dtype=tf.float32)
#     x_tensor = tf.cast(x_tensor, tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(x_tensor)
        output = model(x_tensor)
    DyDX = t.gradient(output, x_tensor)
    dy_t = DyDX[:, 5:6]
    R_pred=dy_t
    # loss_data = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(yTrue - yPred), axis=-1)
    loss_PDE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(R_pred))
    return loss_PDE

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss=customLoss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=15)
```

After execution, I get this `ValueError`:

`ValueError: Passed in object of type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>, not tf.Tensor`

When I change `loss=customLoss` to `loss='mse'`, the model starts training, but using that `customLoss` is the whole point. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `tf.keras` throughout your program instead of `keras´.

Comment: I replaced all keras instances with tf.keras. I am still getting the previous ValueError. Any suggestions? @xdurch0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from *model.input* in the loss function, If I understand your code correctly, you can use the loss :

```
def custom_loss_pass(model, x_tensor):
    def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        with tf.GradientTape() as t:
            t.watch(x_tensor)
            output = model(x_tensor)
        DyDX = t.gradient(output, x_tensor)
        dy_t = DyDX[:, 5:6]
        R_pred=dy_t
        # loss_data = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(yTrue - yPred), axis=-1)
        loss_PDE = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(R_pred))
        return loss_PDE
    return custom_loss
```

And then:

```
model.compile(loss=custom_loss_pass(model, X), optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am not sure it does what you want but at least it works!

Comment: That was IT! It's training now. Thank you!