# Is it possible to make a custom for regression loss function in keras considering the previous output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a CNN image regression model. I want to put a penalty term in the loss function to penalize if the current prediction is greater than the previous expectation.

Is there a way to write a code using Keras instead of using `tf.GradientTape()`?

(This thread looks similar what I want to ask
[Custom loss function with Gradient Tape, TF2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597055/custom-loss-function-with-gradient-tape-tf2-6))

Here's the data description.
My data is video image set and I want to predict how many times left before abnormal event happens.

Therefore, the image label should be decreasing as close to the abnormal label.
(For example, the label of abnormal would be 0 and the previous image would be 1, and the two images before, that image label would be 2.)

So, my prediction also decrease and I want to put penalty term if the current prediction is above the previous prediction.

Here's the model architecture code. I used pretrained VGG16 model and adapted it as regression model.

```
initial_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights = 'imagenet',include_top = False)
initial_model.trainable = False

func_model_p = keras.Sequential()
inputs = keras.Input(shape = (700,100,3))
func_model_p.add(inputs)

func_model_p.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
func_model_p.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))

# Prepare the metrics.
train_mse_metric_p = keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()
val_mse_metric_p = keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()
```

And this code is for the tf.GradientTape. I want to change this code for Keras.

````
for e in range(epochs):
    for i in range(len(y_train_d_noshuffle)):   
        with  tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            image = np.expand_dims(X_train_d_noshuffle[i], axis=0)
            y_hat = func_model_p(image, training=True)

            previous_value = previous_list[-1]
            violation_term = tf.constant(max( (y_hat - previous_value) , 0), dtype=tf.float32) 

            try:
                if y_train_d_noshuffle[i] < y_train_d_noshuffle[i+1]:
                    violation_term = 0
            except: pass

            y_train_c = tf.constant(y_train_d_noshuffle[i])

            mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(y_train_c, y_hat)
            # calculate loss
            loss_value =  mse + violation_term
            previous_list.append(y_hat)

            train_mse_sum = train_mse_sum + mse
            train_penalty_sum = train_penalty_sum + violation_term
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, func_model_p.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, func_model_p.trainable_weights))

        # Update training metric.
        train_mse_metric_p.update_state(y_train_d_noshuffle[i], y_hat)

        # Display metrics at the end of each epoch.
        train_mse = train_mse_metric_p.result().numpy()

    print(f'epochs: {e}, train_mse_sum: {train_mse_sum}, train_penalty_sum: {float(train_penalty_sum)}') ```



Please let me know if you know the way! 

Thank you in advance!
````

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit